# How to make a tie fly up/down with physics

Tags: animation, physics

I'm having trouble on how to make a Tie have physics so i don't have to animate the Tie.

Example, if i make the character Jump the Tie should also move/rotate how it should be. (Without animating it) (just like how the ponytailed hair would do if you jump)

Could anyone explain how i should do it/step by step if it's possible.

Comment: Hello :). What have you tried so far and where exactly are you stuck? This site isn't meant for full tutorials :).

Comment: you could try using a cloth animation and/or use force or wind fields?

Comment: Softbody physics works for ponytails and could work for the tie, too. But I think cloth sim is better for a tie because you can pin it tighter

Comment: To avoid glitches, I might put softbody on a curve instead and then deform the tie to it.